# Does a domain joined Windows 10 computer have built-in tools to query AD/LDAP?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-domain, ldap

I'm on a domain joined Windows 10 Computer and want to query the attributes of my own user account. Are there any built-in tools for that?

It is not an admin computer and I don't have RSAT installed. My computer does not seem to have:

- `dsget`
- `dsquery`
- `ldapsearch`
- `ldp`
- PowerShell `ActiveDirectory` module

Are there any other tools built-in? I mean, there must be *something*, because at least my computer is able to query the AD, but are there tools that I can also use as a user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows has the [ADSI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/adsi-reference) interface available to programs, which supports general LDAP access.

PowerShell has access to ADSI via `System.DirectoryServices` types:

- The `[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]` [type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry) (aliased to `[ADSI]`) represents a specific entry – when given an LDAP object, its attributes directly correspond to the LDAP entry's attributes:

  ```
  $obj = [adsi] "LDAP://CN=foo,OU=bar,DC=example,DC=com"
  echo $obj.displayName
  $obj | fl *
  ```

  You don't need to specify a server – Windows will use the AD directory by default. (The `LDAP://` part is case-sensitive; this is an [ADSI binding string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/binding-string), not a URL.)
- The `[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]` [type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) (aliased to `[ADSISearcher]`) represents an LDAP *search query* which can be used to find your user DN if you don't already know it:

  ```
  $qry = [adsisearcher] "(sAMAccountName=stackprotector)"
  $qry.FindAll().Path
  ```

  More verbose example copied from some-or-other MSDN docs page (in AD, searching for the `anr` pseudo-attribute is how GUI tools resolve names):

  ```
  $qry = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
  $qry.Filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(anr=Stack))'
  $qry.SearchRoot = 'LDAP://OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=com'
  $qry.FindAll()
  ```

But ADSI is originally a COM+ API that predates PowerShell and even .NET in general, so of course Microsoft has examples for using it [from VBScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/enumerating-objects) and [from ADODB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/getting-started-with-scripting-for-adsi) (and even [from ASP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/getting-started-with-asp-for-adsi), not that it helps here).

---

You should also be able to install and use some RSAT tools without needing any special privileges (aside from local Windows admin to do the installation). By default, the directory is wide open to any authenticated client.

You can use third-party LDAP clients with AD – the domain controllers will accept authentication using your *user* credentials, which is how most Windows GUI tools look up data in AD in the first place (with the machine join account being needed only for some tasks). However, it's best to use clients which support Kerberos authentication via GSSAPI or GSS-SPNEGO, as that's guaranteed to work with any AD setup. Tools which use NTLM or "simple bind" (password authentication) may or may not work depending on domain configuration.

For example, [SysInternals ADExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer) comes from Microsoft and works without installation. (When prompted for server details, leave all fields blank and just click "Connect".)

(The RSAT tools "ADSIEdit" and "dsa.msc" can technically be used without a full installation, indeed even official Microsoft instructions used to say "extract these files from the .cab and regsvr32 them", but you *do* need Windows local admin access for the `regsvr32` part.

Answer (score 2):

From user1686's excellent [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1720069/1077440), I derived the following line to display the attributes of the currently logged on user account:

```
[adsi] ([adsisearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$env:USERNAME)").FindAll().Path | Format-List *
```

---

## Further useful queries

1. Get all members of a group (given by sAMAccountName):

   ```
   ([adsisearcher] "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$(([adsi] ([adsisearcher] "(sAMAccountName=REPLACE_ME_WITH_GROUPNAME)").FindOne().Path).distinguishedName)))").FindAll() | %{[adsi] $_.Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMAccountName} | Sort-Object
   ```
2. Check if a user (given by sAMAccountName) is a member of a group (given by sAMAccountName):

   ```
   ([adsisearcher] "(&(sAMAccountName=REPLACE_ME_WITH_USERNAME)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$(([adsi] ([adsisearcher] "(sAMAccountName=REPLACE_ME_WITH_GROUPNAME)").FindOne().Path).distinguishedName)))").FindAll().Count -gt 0
   ```
3. Get the state of an account given by sAMAccountName:

   ```
   ([adsi] ([adsisearcher] "(sAMAccountName=REPLACE_ME)").FindOne().Path).userAccountControl | %{[PSCustomObject]@{AccountDisabled = [bool] ($_ -band 2); AccountLockedOut = [bool] ($_ -band 16); PasswordDoesNotExpire = [bool] ($_ -band 65536); PasswordExpired = [bool] ($_ -band 8388608);}}
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   AccountDisabled AccountLockedOut PasswordDoesNotExpire PasswordExpired
   --------------- ---------------- --------------------- ---------------
             False            False                 False           False
   ```
4. Get all objects by a sAMAccountName pattern:

   ```
   ([adsisearcher] "(sAMAccountName=REPLACE_ME*)").FindAll() | %{[adsi] $_.Path} | Select-Object -Property distinguishedName, sAMAccountName
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`net.exe` with the `/domain` switch queries the AD:

```
REM Show account details, like password metadata and group memberships 
net user %USERNAME% /domain

REM Show members of a group
net group "domain users" /domain
    
REM Show password policy
net accounts /domain


REM List all usernames
net user /domain

REM List all groups
net group /domain
    

net config workstation
net stats workstation
```

More info on parameters is available at [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/net.html), output examples at [René Nyffenegger's site](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/System32/net_exe/index) and historic background on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(command)). The [official docs of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771865(v=ws.11)) are incomplete, switching between versions might help.